# Angular8 form input fields disabled

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Angular8 and have a form used to update a product. My problem however is this forms input fields and submit button is disabled. Can anyone advise what I am doing wrong?  I would expect to be able to edit the input fields text and submit the form.

html:

```
<div class="bodyClass">
    <h1>{{title | titlecase}}</h1>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <form *ngIf="angForm && productData" [formGroup]="angForm" novalidate>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4">Product Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name" #name/>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['name'].invalid && (angForm.controls['name'].dirty || angForm.controls['name'].touched)"
                    class="alert alert-danger">
                    <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['name'].errors.required">
                        Product Name is required.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button (click)="updateProduct(name.value)" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
                        [disabled]="angForm.invalid">
                        Update Product
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { PermissionsService } from '../../services/permissions.service';
import { Permissions } from '../../model/permissions';
import { ProductsService } from '../../services/products.service';
import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service';
import { Product } from '../../model/product';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-productsupdate',
  templateUrl: './productsupdate.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./productsupdate.component.css']
})
export class ProductsupdateComponent implements OnInit {

  angForm: FormGroup;
  private permissionsObservable: Observable<Permissions>; 
  private showData: boolean = true;
  private title: string;
  private productData: Product;

  constructor(private _permissionsService: PermissionsService, private _productService: ProductsService,
              private dataService: DataService, private fb: FormBuilder) {
                this.createForm();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.title = 'Update Product';
    if (this.dataService.serviceData) {
      console.log(this.dataService.serviceData);
      this.productData = this.dataService.serviceData; 
    }
  }

  ngDoCheck() {
    if (this.productData) {
      this.angForm.get('name').setValue(this.productData.name);
    }
  }

  createForm() {
    this.angForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required ],
      decription: ['', Validators.required ],
      status: ['', Validators.required ]
    });
  }

  updateProduct() {
    console.log('submit');
  }
}
```

Screenprint:

[image: You can see that the button is disabled and the input text is non-editable]

You can see that the button is disabled and the input text is non-editable.

Comment: the "decription" field (must be description?) has no value ever and is required. BTW, why no tchange the value of "name" in ngOnInit -not using ngDoCheck-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `ngDoCheck`, so everytime angular runs it, for example when you are trying to type, and `productData` is populated,

```
this.angForm.get('name').setValue(this.productData.name);
```

is run, and thus always setting the value making it **seem** that you cannot edit the field.

Since this can also be a race condition, as forms are asynchronous, I suggest building the form after getting value to `productData` (if getting value). So remove the `createForm()` function from constructor and add it later on:

```
if (this.dataService.serviceData) {
  console.log(this.dataService.serviceData);
  this.productData = this.dataService.serviceData; 
}
this.createForm();
```

Modify the `createForm` function a bit:

```
createForm() {
  this.angForm = this.fb.group({
    name: [this.productData.name || '', Validators.required ],
    description: [this.productData.description || ''],
    status: [this.productData.status || '']
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try.

Comment: That works, I can now edit the input field, thank you. However the submit button is still disabled.

Comment: Well, you have also `description` and `status` that are required, so unless those fields have values, button will be disabled as the form is invalid.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.  All working now.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: I added `status` and `description` exactly the same as `name`. However, now I get the following error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'setValue' of null
    at ProductUpdateComponent.ngOnInit (product-update.component.ts:36)`.   Line 36 is where the controller does: `this.angForm.get('description').setValue(this.productData.description);`.  Not sure why I cannot get `'description'` from the form?

Comment: it's not the issue that you are getting it from the form, but from `productData`. Does that object has such a field? You need to add a check for that, and if does not exist, I guess you want to set an empty string for the form?

Comment: I am a bit confused, because when I `console.log(this.productData.description);`, it prints out a value of `'active'`.  But `console.log(this.angForm.get('description'));` prints `null`.

Comment: Please create a stackblitz for this, soooooo much easier to help. Also the issue could be that there is a race condition, angular forms are in fact asynchronous. Where do you console log `this.angForm.get('description')`

Comment: I log the `this.angForm.get('description')` in the `ngOnInit()` function. Do you think it's not there yet?

Comment: You can also create the fields with status "disabled" `new Form({value:'',disabled:true},Validators.required)`

Comment: @Eliseo, well OP does not want to disable any fields to my understanding :)

Comment: @Richard, it is possible that the form has not been completely built. Try `AfterViewInit` hook

Comment: @AJT_82, we can choose between remove validators or disabled the fields. If you has a complex validators, I would prefer disabled/enabled than remove/add the validators, but it's only another option

Comment: @Eliseo Where in the question do you read that OP wants to disable a field or removing validators? I don't understand how your comments are related to this question?

Comment: I just want an enabled field for `description` with no validation. I can remove `Validators.required`, but I still get the same error that when I try call `this.angForm.get('description')`, it is `null`.

Comment: @Richard Ok, I see now you have a typo. You have built your form with `decription` not `description` :)

Comment: I now also get `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`. This wasn't happening before, so I guess it's a timing issue.

Comment: @AZT_82 - it's working now. It was the spelling mistake for `description` that you spotted.  All working now.  I appreciate you patience.

Comment: Haah, okay, great!! :) Still updated my answer, you can also do it like I updated or keep it as you have :)